# Call a php script from javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery-ui, rest, autocomplete

I need to call my REST API that is written in PHP from a javascript script.  A similar situation I can point to is the jquery ui autocomplete plugin. When you specify an external php script for the source attribute, it reads the output from the php script, and uses that as the autocomplete options.

Comment: you can use `$.ajax`, `$.post`, `$.get`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could use the jQuery ajax function:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Thanks, and can anyone explain why I got so downvoted, so I can format my question better next time?  I did do several google searches before asking this question, but was unsuccessful.

Answer (score 3):

[AJAX](http://google.com/search?q=ajax). That is all.

If you have any more specific issues, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an AJAX request (if I understood the question)
If your API is written in myapi.php, you can:

```
var word = "The Word";
$.ajax({
    url: "myapi.php?action=searchfor&word="+word,
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

...assuming you're using jQuery, of course :)